# How to pivot up data at 2 levels

Tags: sas

I have the data set as below. I want to pivot up the data such that the sales of each ID

```
ID Country     Sales_total   sales_source
 1  EU            1200    warehouse
 2  US            1000    store
 1  EU            1500    store
 1  EU            4000    store
 3  EU            2000    warehouse
 4  US            3000   store
 4  US            7500    warehouse
 4  US            9000    warehouse
```

I want the output as below. You will find that for each ID I have pivoted up the data such that the sales displays the sum of sales of that sales_source. E. g ( ID 1 has a sales of 5400 (1500+4000) in stores and 1200 in warehouse. similar is for ID 4 where sales is = 12000 (3000+9000) in stores and 7500 in warehouse. Can someone help me write the code for this?

```
ID Country     Sales_total   sales_source
 1  EU            1200    warehouse
 2  US            1000    store
 1  EU            5400    store
 3  EU            2000    warehouse
 4  US            1200    store
 4  US            7500    warehouse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want an aggregation query (although your desired results are not quite correct):

```
proc sql;
    select id, country, sum(sales_total) as sales_total, sales_source
    from dataset
    group by id, country, sales_source;
```